# Setting color of the button through theme in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to have same color of all the buttons in app developing in flutter. I tried to set it through **ThemeData(ButtonThemeData) but there is nothing.

```
theme: ThemeData(
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue[800],
        accentColor: Colors.orange,
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
          buttonColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
      ),
```

my button code is

```
Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  child: FlatButton(
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                      side: BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    child: Text("Take Quiz"),
                  ),
                ),
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```dart
theme: ThemeData(
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        primaryColor: Colors.lightBlue[800],
        accentColor: Colors.orange,
        buttonColor: Colors.blue, //this line here
        ),
```

Comment: that's strange. are you trying to change the bg color of the button or the button text color?

Comment: hey I got a way

Comment: ah, I didn't know you were using `ThemeData.dark()`

Answer (score 0):

I got it. Actually the problem was at the

```
ThemeData.dark()
```

It is a pre-defined theme. And if you want to change anything in it, you have to use

```
ThemeData.dark().copywith(//here you will define your scheme)
```